# How I can find out the foreign wrapper that a foreign table belongs to?

Tags: postgresql, system-tables

I have found that the following query lists all my foreign tables in my PostgreSQL database:

```
select * from information_schema."tables" where table_type='FOREIGN TABLE';
```

Now I want to find out the foreign wrapper connection that a database is referred into. In this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/244100/118215) the following query lists all my foreign wrappers:

```
SELECT fdw.fdwname AS "Name",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(fdw.fdwowner) AS "Owner",
  fdw.fdwhandler::pg_catalog.regproc AS "Handler",
  fdw.fdwvalidator::pg_catalog.regproc AS "Validator"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_foreign_data_wrapper fdw
ORDER BY 1;
```

Now what I want is to find out how to combine this information in order to find out in which foreign wrapper a foreign table belongs into. Do you have any idea how to query that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
    SELECT
      foreign_table_name,
      foreign_server_name
    FROM
      information_schema.foreign_tables
```

You may find more information on `information_schema.foreign_tables` in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-foreign-tables.html).